# Downloading and installing programs in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

It’s the first time I use Ubuntu and I don’t have a clue how to download and install programs. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/addremove-install.html

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has pre-installed Software center where you can download software. Otherwise you can get your program from command line with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install program
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways using which you can download programs, packages and applications in Ubuntu. Most common of them are :-

- Installing Graphically

  1. [**Ubuntu Software Center**/**Software Center**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center) (For Ubuntu 15.10 and prior versions)
  2. [**Ubuntu Software**/**GNOME Software**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software) (For Ubuntu 16.04 and later versions)
  3. [**Synaptic Package Manager**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software))

     Synaptic doesn't come pre-installed in Ubuntu. So you have to install it first. You can install it either by using Ubuntu Software Center/Ubuntu Software or by typing `sudo apt-get install synaptic` in the terminal. Once installed, you can open it, and search for the application that you want to install, and just mark it for installation.
  4. [**GDebi Package Installer**](https://launchpad.net/gdebi)

     **gdebi** is a simple tool to install **.deb** files.
     It lets you install local deb packages resolving and installing
     its dependencies. It has a graphical user interface but can also be used in your terminal. *apt* does the same, but only for remote (http, ftp) located package repositories. GDebi doesn't come pre-installed in Ubuntu. So you have to install it first. You can install it either by using Ubuntu Software Center/Ubuntu Software or by typing `sudo apt-get install gdebi` in the terminal.

     **NOTE**: Manually downloaded **.deb** file can also be installed by opening it in the Ubuntu Software Center/Ubuntu Software by double-clicking it and then installing it from the Ubuntu Software Center/Ubuntu Software !
- Installing via Terminal

  1. Using [**APT(Advanced Packaging Tool)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool)

     (i) Open Terminal by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or by going in your Dashboard and searching for Terminal.

     (ii) Then type the following command in it :- `sudo apt-get install package` (Replace "package" with the name of the package in the given command.

     (iii) Sometimes you have to add repositories or PPAs before installing packages. You can do so by typing the commands given below in the terminal :-

     `sudo add-apt-repository repository_name`

     `sudo apt-get update`

     `sudo apt-get install application_name`

     Replace **repository_name** and **application_name** with the name of repository and application respectively.
  2. Manually downloaded **.deb** file can also be installed using Terminal. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, type the following commands in it :-

     `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file`

     `sudo apt-get install -f`
  3. You can also install applications from **.tar.gz** or **.tar.bz2** files by taking a look at one of the links given below :-

     (i) [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

     (ii) http://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/